# Transposed Matrix algebra in Econometrics (Greene)

Tags: matrix-calculus, transpose

I am working Econometrics Analysis by W.H.Greene and I am a bit stuck on some matrix calculations. I did studied Matrix algebra, but I cannot remember any rule concerning simplification or change of signe when dealing with transposed matrix. I looked a lot on the web but couldn't find anything that could help me resolve it.

For example, it is stated page 21 that the sum of square errors is :
S = (y-XB)'(y-XB)

Which can be developed to obtain:
y′y − B′X′y − y′XB + b′X′XB

But then, it goes directly to:
 y′y − 2y′XB + B′X′XB

I really don't understand how -B'X'y - y'XB = -2y'XB
I know the rule (AB)'=B'A' and the associative multiplication of matrices, but I cannot understand how the author get this result.

Also, he later differentiates y′y − 2y′XB + B′X′XB by B, and gets −2X'y + 2X'XB, a result I cannot get neither. Where do the 2  comes from in the final expression (the 2X'XB part)? And how -2y'X = -2X'y  (first part of the final expression?

I hope someone will be able to help me.

Thanks in advance,
Mathieu

P.S : In the text book, A' is used for transposed matrix.

Comment: Presumably, $S$ is a scalar, so all of the terms in the expansion of the product are also scalars. This means in particular that $y'XB=(y'XB)'=B'X'y$.

Comment: Could you please tell me the dimensions of matrix $X,B$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the work in the expression is that of manipulation and remanipulation. What I mean is that we are only trying to have a comfortable position by changing to equivalent values. In this instance, we have:
(Y-Xb)'(Y-Xb)= Y'Y- Y'Xb- X'b'Y+X'b'Xb 
Remember Y= Xb, Therefore
Y'Y- (Xb)'Xb-X'b'Y+X'b'Xb= Y'Y- X'b'Xb-X'b'Y+X'b'Xb= Y'Y-X'b'Y- X'b'Y+ X'b'Xb= Y'Y- 2X'b'Y+X'b'Y= Y'Y- X'b'Y
Therefore, (Y-Xb)'(Y-Xb) = Y'Y- X'b'Y

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0):

$y'$, $X$, and $B$ are respectively of dimensions $(1 \times n)$, $(n \times K)$, $(K \times 1)$.

Hence, $y'Xb$ is a scalar $s$, and $s'=s$. The same applies to $b'X'y$.

Thus, $y'Xb = (y'Xb)' = (Xb)'y = b'X'y$

Yielding $-y'Xb - b'X'y = -2b'X'y$